# Dynamically add directive inside an other

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a directive `MyCustomButton`. Let's say it changes the background of a button.
I want this directive to add the Material `md-raised-button` directive.

But I don't find how to do that. I can add an attribute with `@HostBinding`, but it's not a directive.

I want to do that because my users don't want to add a lot of directives on their divs. so, instead of that :

```
<button md-raised-button custom-directive1 custom-directive2...>Button</button>
```

I want that :

```
<button my-custom-directive>Button</button>
```

who add all others directives.

Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

> who add all others directives.

You can compose directives e.g. `my-custom-directive` can have the template as `<button md-raised-button custom-directive1 custom-directive2...`.

Of course you can also pass default values to sub directives when composing etc. based on *your requirements*. Have fun